# MySQL Show if match

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one is the catalogue, that contains all the info for all the products; the second one is the inventory, that contains only certain products for certain shops.

catalogue is called pruebas, the structure is:

```
cod varchar(10) PRI     
nom varchar(100)
tip varchar(50) 
des varchar(500)
pre double  
cla varchar(3)
fcm varchar(20)
cmb char(1)
```

Where cod is the product's code, nom is the description, tip is the model, des is for comments, pre is the price, cla is the key type for the product, fcm is the modification date, and cmb is to identify if the product has some subproducts.

The inventory is called inventario, the structure is:

```
loc varchar(20)
cod varchar(10)
can double
cve varchar(3)
mdl varchar(6)
```

Where loc is the store for the product, cod is the code for matching with prueba, can is the quantity of the product, cve is the key type and mdl is where the product is located in the store.

I need a query that shows all the content from prueba ordered by code, but, if there's a match between prueba and inventario the quantity must be shown, and if not, a 0 must be shown. To be more specific:

If I have the code 2007 in prueba and the code 2007 in inventario for the shop "XTORR", the quantity of the product must be shown. Like:

```
Code    Product              Model      $  Key Quantity
2007    MICA ESPEJO SE C1904 XPERIA M   59  MI    5
```

But, if the product does not appear in inventario, it should show 0:

```
Code    Product                     Model      $   Key Quantity
2000    FUNDA MORRAL PERSONAJES 2             199   F   0
```

I have this code, but it throws zero with all quantities.

```
select 
prueba.cod as 'Código', 
prueba.nom as 'Descripción', 
prueba.tip as 'Modelo', 
prueba.pre as 'Precio', 
prueba.cla as 'Clave' , 
if(prueba.cod = inventario.cod, inventario.can,0) as ' Cantidad'
from prueba,inventario
where inventario.loc = 'XTORR'
group by prueba.cod
order by CHAR_LENGTH(prueba.cod), prueba.cod;
```

Help, please, I could not find a similar thread.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to compare `NULL` values using arithmetic operators. An equality of inequality involving `NULL` always returns `NULL` in MySQL. [Read the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting from two tables using an inner join (the comma between table names) instead of a left join. Then you want to use ISNULL to check for null values.

```
SELECT prueba.cod as 'Código',
  prueba.nom as 'Descripción', 
  prueba.tip as 'Modelo', 
  prueba.pre as 'Precio', 
  prueba.cla as 'Clave',
  IFNULL(inventario.can, 0) as 'Cantidad'
FROM prueba
  LEFT OUTER JOIN inventario ON (prueba.cod = inventario.cod and inventario.loc = 'xtorr')
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(prueba.cod), prueba.cod;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following query

```
  select 
  prueba.cod as 'Código', 
  prueba.nom as 'Descripción', 
  prueba.tip as 'Modelo', 
  prueba.pre as 'Precio'
  prueba.cla as 'Clave',COUNT(if(inventario.cod IS NOT NULL)) as Quantity from prueba 
  left join inventario  on   prueba.cod = inventario.cod
  GROUP BY prueba.cod, prueba.nom,prueba.tip,prueba.pre,prueba.cla
```